# How to make a file with a variable as the name

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to make a log file for my application but when I try to make the file with a variable as the name I get a "FileNotFound" error.

Example:

```
log_file_name = str("log" + "/" + str(current_time.month) + "/" + str(current_time.day) + "/" + str(current_time.year) + ".txt")
log_txt = open(log_file_name, "a")
```

This gives me a FileNotFound error like this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\taco\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\mygame.py", line 7, in <module>
    log_txt = open(log_file_name, "a")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'log/8/14/2022.txt'
```

The below method would give me the same error.

```
log_txt = open (str("log" + "/" + str(current_time.month) + "/" + str(current_time.day) + "/" + str(current_time.year)) + ".txt", "a")
```

But if I do something simple like this it creates the file as it should:

```
log_txt = open("log.txt", "a")
```

*Edit* I forgot to add that the same happens above when using "a+" instead of "a"

Comment: `log/8/14/2022.txt` Slashes in filenames mean _subdirectories_.  This would attempt to open a file named `2022.txt` in the subdirectory `log/8/14`.  If you don't already have a subdirectory named `log/8/14`, this won't work.

Comment: Thank you for your help! :D I feel very silly for not noticing this lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, instead of concatenating multiple strings, just use `f-string` which would make your code look something like this:

`log_file_name = f"log/{current_time.month}/{current_time.day}/{current_time.year}.txt")`

It does the same thing but is a bit easier on the eyes.

Now to answer your question, the reason you're getting this exception is you're using `/` to seperate the variables which would trick python into thinking the variables are directories.

To fix this, **remove the / in your filename string**, so that it would look like this:

`f"log{current_time.month}{current_time.day}{current_time.year}.txt"`

Comment: Even more clear and sortable with `f"log-{current_time.date().isoformat()}.txt"`.